# Android studio not running the application showing "force close"

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, java-native-interface, logcat

The app has no bugs. I tried in debugging mode working perfectly.

When I am pressing the run button, the app was not running in the device.
Instead it was showing "Waiting for Debugger" with "force close" button.

I tried with restart android studio, restart PC.
Uninstalled application and re-install, same issue coming.
The run button always showing that force close dialog. 
The same logcat value coming continuously.

When I am pressing the debug button it was opening in the debug mode properly.

Logcat :

```
03-03 12:31:18.993 16979-16979/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-03 12:31:19.253 16979-16979/helix.ridioandroidstudio W/ActivityThread: Application helix.ridioandroidstudio is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-03 12:31:19.353 16979-16979/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
03-03 12:31:19.533 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:19.553 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:20.033 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:20.043 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:20.533 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:20.553 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:21.033 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:21.043 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:21.533 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:21.543 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:22.033 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:22.043 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:22.543 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:22.593 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-03 12:31:23.033 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-03 12:31:23.043 16979-16984/helix.ridioandroidstudio I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try rebooting your device and run again

Answer (score 2):

I deleted all the files from the apk folder and then run.

```
 adb shell am clear-debug-app
```

Resolved without restarting the device.

Answer (score 1):

From http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html

This error occurs If you’re using the emulator, CheckJNI is on by default. If you’re working with an Android device, use the following adb command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1
```

This won’t affect already-running apps, but any app launched from that point on will have CheckJNI enabled. In this case, you’ll see something like this in your logcat output the next time each app starts:

```
D Late-enabling CheckJNI
```

If you don’t see this, your app was probably already running; **you just need to force stop it and start it again**.

Also check [JNI tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)